# how can i reverse this data in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I'am trying to reverse this JSON before i get if from MYSQL so i want the last to be the first  code ;

```
@GetMapping("/getDataTrashCan")
public List<TrashCanResponse> sendData() {
  List<TrashCanResponse> trashCanResponses = trashCanRepository.findAll() ;
  return trashCanResponses ;
}
```

and this is my return :

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "humidity": 60,
    "distance": 157,
    "temperature": 29
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "humidity": 60,
    "distance": 156,
    "temperature": 29
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "humidity": 60,
    "distance": 157,
    "temperature": 29
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "humidity": 60,
    "distance": 157,
    "temperature": 29
  }
```

i think it have a query code for reverse in mysql.
so how can i reverse this data using JPA and query !!

Comment: what do you mean by reversing the datas? something like `92 :"erutarepmet"` for `"temperature": 29` ?

Comment: nope , reverse rows